# Realm : How do manage permission on table

Tags: permissions, realm

What kind of strategy can be used to manage access rights using realm object server ? I couldn't find any information on the matter.
The scenario is the following : I use a realm object server to sync an app on mutliple devices. Some tables must have "read only" access for example , whereas other must be read/write for a given user.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by the documentation, currently, it is only possible to set permissions for a whole Realm file, not individual permissions. Progress for this tracked in the following issue: https://github.com/realm/realm-mobile-platform/issues/22